# Determinant of complex matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, determinant

How is the determinant of a complex matrix calculated?
Is it the same algorithm as for real matrices, but the determinant itself is complex instead of real?

(I was unable to find any hints with google...)

Comment: yes, same calculation but with complex numbers.

Comment: The same definition is used. If you want to compute the determinant, I would use a LU factorization (with partial pivoting) unless I knew something more about the structure.

Comment: @copper.hat: I use the LU thing for the real matrices. I wondered how to do the same thing on complex matrices. For the inverse matrix; I can build a 2n x 2n matrix with real and imaginary parts and use the same function as for real matrices (see http://home.earthlink.net/~w6rmk/math/matinv.htm). Therefore I am searching for a likewise method for the determinant.

Comment: @joe: Do the computations in complex arithmetic, or look at the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/166244/27978 for example (well, this computes $|\det A|$).

Comment: @copper.hat: That's what I was looking for!

Comment: @joe: By the way, I would be very wary of using determinants in a computation. What are you using them for?

Comment: @copper.hat: At work I'm writing a generic program for data aquisition and analysis. Where 'data' mean any real measurement data from a CNC machine (kinetic, electric, ...). Within the tool, there are a lot of math helpers (polynom fit, FFT, ...). So the matrix calculations makes the whole thing complete. To your question: I'm just the provider of functionality, I can't foresee what users (50+) do with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The determinant is calculated in the **same way**, regardless of what field the numbers in the elements of the matrix are taken from.

Comment: So a determinant is always of the same type as the matrix elements (real, complex, or even matrices)?

Comment: @joe Yes, that's correct. Although of course a product of complex numbers can sometimes be real, and so on.

Comment: If the complex matrix is Hermitian that its determinant is Real.

Comment: @kaka would that hold true as the matrices extend to higher dimensions? I'd imagine a 5D matrix could have an imaginary or even quaternion determinant with that still being the case

Answer (score 3):

The type signature of the determinant is indeed not prominently displayed in the english language Wikipedia [article on determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant), hit #3 in my google search, after the German Duden wordbook entry and the German language article.

It says

> Although most often used for matrices whose entries are real or
>   complex numbers, the definition of the determinant only involves
>   addition, subtraction and multiplication, and so it can be defined for
>   square matrices with entries taken from any commutative ring.

in the introduction which hints on the result type, if you consider algebraic closure.

On the other hand the [article on multilinear forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_multilinear_form) does:
$$
f: V^n \to K
$$
for $V$ being a $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$.

Of course you need to be familiar with the Weierstraß characterisation of the determinant as a (normed) alternating multilinear form to look there, which is not linked in the definition in the article on determinants and is buried more deep down in that text.

Kind of surprising for a basic article which should have gotten many eyeballs already.

Comment: Agreed. On the other hand, some math articles on Wikipedia are written by nerd mathematicans (sorry for that!), that even engineers don't understand. I hit such articles a lot of times, when I try to use the math in real-world applications. Doing my job means I *must* understand how the math works so I can implement it into a program.

Comment: I was surprised that this information is hidden that much. Of course you need it for an implementation.

Comment: That's true. As mentioned, Wikipedia writers sadly too often don't have practical usage in mind when writing articles. This 'minor' information is 'not so important' when explaining things, but is IS essential when you want to solve real problems!

Answer (score 0):

If you can diagonalize a matrix, be it real or complex, the diagonal product of that matrix will yield the determinant.