# Finding Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given a matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\
-1 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$.
The determinant of the matrix is $(9+6+2(2+3))$. What's the trick behind the summation. Do block matrices help us here and how?

Comment: http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/math316/transp/3_2.pdf

Comment: I want to know the rule for the sum $9+6+2(2+3)$

Comment: Read the article I posted. If you expand along the first row then the first determinant you come to is of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ which is $9$. I attached the link because it will help you.

Comment: The det is correct.

Comment: Thanks to Faraad. The sum came

Comment: Notably, this is the Kronecker product
$$
\pmatrix{1&2\\-1&3} \otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Swapping the middle rows and then the middle columns gives us
$$\pmatrix{1&2&0&0\\-1&3&0&0\\0&0&1&2\\0&0&-1&3}.$$
That's surely more tractable?

Comment: the answer should be $25$

Comment: Sure it is. That works faster

Answer (score 2):

**A more general approach [(Laplace expansion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion):**

Hint: Suppose there is a $3\times3$ matrix, then its determinant is given by:

$$\Delta_{3\times3}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\end{vmatrix}
=a_{11}\begin{vmatrix}
a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}
-a_{12}\begin{vmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}
+a_{13}\begin{vmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{22}\\
a_{31} & a_{32}
\end{vmatrix};$$
Similarly if there is a $4\times4$ matrix, then it's determinant is given by:
$$\Delta_{4\times4}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}\end{vmatrix}\\
$$
$$=a_{11}\begin{vmatrix}
a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}
\end{vmatrix}
-a_{12}\begin{vmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & a_{33} & a_{24}\\
a_{41} & a_{43} & a_{44}
\end{vmatrix}
+a_{13}\begin{vmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{34}\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{44}
\end{vmatrix}
-a_{14}\begin{vmatrix}
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43}
\end{vmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I would have done this by expansion on the first column.  That gives
$\left|\begin{array} {ccc} 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 3\end{array}\right|- \left|\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 3 \end{array}\right|$.

Now, seeing the lone "3" in the middle of the first 3 by 3 matrix, I would expand it on the second row, and seeing the lone "2" in first row of the second matrix, I would expand it on the first row:
$3\left|\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 3\end{array}\right|+ 2\left|\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2 \\ -1 & 3\end{array}\right|= 3(3+ 2)+ 2(3+ 2)= 15+ 10= 25$

To get the expression you have, 9+ 6+ 2(2+ 3), instead expand the first of those 3 by 3 matrices on the first column and the second on the first row:
$\left|\begin{array}{cc}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{array}\right|- \left|\begin{array}{cc}0 & 2 \\3 & 0\end{array}\right|- 2\left|\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ -1 & 3 \end{array}\right|= 9- (-6)- 2(3+ 2)= 9+ 6- 2(2+ 3)= 25$.

Answer (score 0):

First, substract twice the second *column* from the last one, getting:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 5
\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{\text{develop 2nd row}}\longrightarrow\begin{vmatrix}1&2&0\\\!-1&3&0\\0&0&\color{red}5\end{vmatrix}=5\begin{vmatrix}1&2\\\!-1&3\end{vmatrix}=5(3+2)=25$$

What's the trick? The very first step, which was carried on to have as many zeros as possible in some row/column and then develop on that row/columns. You could has well have begun by adding thrice the first column to the third one and then develop the third row, or add the first row to the third one, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to skin this cat. The given 4x4 matrix is the matrix of the linear transformation $(z_1,z_2)\mapsto (z_1+2z_2,-z_1+3z_3)$ from $\Bbb{C}^2$ to itself, **when we view $\Bbb{C}^2$ as a 4-dimensional vector space over the reals**. To see that use the basis $\{(1,0),(i,0),(0,1),(0,i)\}$.

It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166244/11619) that the determinant of a real 4x4 matrix representing a 2x2 complex matrix is the squared absolute value of the corresponding complex determinant. Therefore your determinant
$$
=(1\cdot3-(-1)\cdot2)^2=25.
$$

---

This trick works whenever you only have 2x2-blocks of the form
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rr}a&-b\\b&a\end{array}\right).
$$
That is the matrix representing multiplication by the complex number $a+bi$ (and we view $\Bbb{C}$ as a 2-dimensional real vector space with basis $\{1,i\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This formula comes from the *Laplace expansion* along a `group of columns`.

In the present case, it was expanded along the `first two columns` and amounts to computing $6$ $2\times2$ determinants. I'll try to explain how it works:

Denote $p_{ij}$ the determinant made up of the elements in the first two columns, and in rows $i$ and $j$. Similarly, denote $q_{ij}$ the determinant of the elements in the last two columns, and in rows $i$ and $j$. The determinant of a $4\times 4$ matrix is given  by
$$\det A=p_{12}q_{34}+ p_{13}q_{24}+ p_{14}q_{23}+ p_{23}q_{14}+ p_{24}q_{13}+ p_{34}q_{12}$$