# Prove SU(n) is a subgroup of SO(2n)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I want to show that SU(n) is a subgroup of SO(2n). I can show the first step, that is, for any $U=U_R + iU_I\in SU(n)$ with $U_R,U_I\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, we identify $U$ with the real $2n\times 2n$ matrix
$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
U_R & - U_I\\
U_I & U_R
\end{pmatrix}
$ and I can show that $X$ is orthogonal, i.e., $XX^T= Id_{2n\times 2n}$. But I do not know how to show that $\det X = 1$. Can someone show we how?

Thank you in advance!

Best,

Stefan

Comment: I think that we always have $\det X=|\det U|^2$. For all $U\in GL_n(\Bbb{C})$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166244/11619). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen more generally, if $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension, then by restriction of scalars any $U \in M_{n \times n}$ gives rise to a square matrix of dimension $n[L:K]$ with determinant $N_{L/K}(\det U)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one nice approach. Denote
$$
P = \pmatrix{I & -iI\\-iI & I},
$$
note that $P^{-1} = \frac 12 P^*$ (where $P^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $P$). Now, note that $\det(X) = \det(P^{-1}XP)$, and verify (via block-matrix multiplication) that
$$
P^{-1}XP = \frac 12 P^*XP = \pmatrix{U_R + iU_I & 0\\0 & U_R - iU_I}.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\det(X) = \det(U) \det(\bar U) = \det(U)\overline{\det(U)} = |\det(U)|^2 = 1.
$$
(In the above, $\bar \cdot$ denotes the complex conjugate, so $\bar U = U_R - iU_I$).